# Python Kivy - display dynamic result in another screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to create a 2 screen app that acts as a dictionary function. I used Kivy and PyDictionary. First screen takes the input of the word, the second screen display the meaning. I struggled to make that work.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from word import dictword, screen_helper
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

final_word = ''


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


sm = Builder.load_string("""
ScreenManager:
    ScreenOne:
        name: "screen1"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            TextInput:
                id: word_name
                text: final_word.text
            Button:
                text: "Change Label on Screen 2"
                on_release:
                    final_word.text = show_data_meaning()
            Button:
                text: "Next Screen"
                on_release:
                    root.current = "screen2"
    ScreenTwo:
        name: "screen2"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: "Default Text"
                id: final_word
            Button:
                text: "Prev Screen"
                on_release:
                    root.current = "screen1"
""")


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

    def show_data_meaning(self, obj):
        dictionary = PyDictionary(self.final_word.text)
        meaning = dictionary.getMeanings()
        return meaning


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I don't know how to pass the value to the second screen by running the show_data_meaning and display the output. This code returns a NameError

```
 NameError: name 'show_data_meaning' is not defined
```

How do I fix my code? I am a beginner of Kivy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `show_data_meaning()` method is a method of the `App`, so your reference to it in the `kv` should be:

```
            on_release:
                final_word.text = app.show_data_meaning()
```

Then in that method, you can access the `final_word` `id` like this:

```
def show_data_meaning(self):
    dictionary = PyDictionary(self.root.ids.final_word.text)
    meaning = dictionary.getMeanings()
    return meaning
```

The `root` of the `App` is the `ScreenManager`, which contains the `id` for `final_word`.

Comment: Thank you John! one little amendment on your tip. In the show_data_meaning() method, I have to refer to self.root.ids.word_name.text, as that is the input word. Then everything works!

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code, Thanks to John!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from word import dictword, screen_helper
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

   

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    # def press(self):
    #     self.ids.final_word.text
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    # def display(self):
    #     self.ids.my_label.text = ScreenOne.ids.text_input.text
    pass


sm = Builder.load_string("""
ScreenManager:
    ScreenOne:
        name: "screen1"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            TextInput:
                id: word_name
                text: final_word.text
            Button:
                text: "Change Label on Screen 2"
                on_release:
                    final_word.text = app.show_data_meaning()
            Button:
                text: "Next Screen"
                on_release:
                    root.current = "screen2"
    ScreenTwo:
        name: "screen2"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: "Default"
                id: final_word
            Button:
                text: "Prev Screen"
                on_release:
                    root.current = "screen1"
""")


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

    def show_data_meaning(self):
        dictionary = PyDictionary(self.root.ids.word_name.text)
        meaning = dictionary.getMeanings()
        return str(meaning)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```